# How do I build a white board stand?

Tags: wood, woodworking, cutting

I'm looking to create a wood stand for a white board.

I have never built anything before and am looking for both insight on what to do and possible schematic ideas. I took basic construction classes in High School, but I was not particularly gifted at it.

The board is 36 inches wide and 24 inches tall.

The board has a trim of 7/8".

The board has a lip for markers and erasers on one 36" side that is 1 3/8" from the back of the board, where there is not a lip (the other 36" side and two 24" sides) it sticks out 3/4" from the back of the board.

I am 5'11" - 6' tall and am  not sure what height would be appropriate for the board either so that it is comfortable to use.

What would be some designs that could work for this?

**Bonus**

I would really like it if I could pivot it 90 Degrees clockwise so that could be used with the 24" side as the bottom.

The [board is here on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004LPYCWW)

Comment: Have you searched for "easel"? Also, you can't rotate it or the lip for markers and erasers will be vertical. Finally, have you considered handing it on a wall -- that's what I did with a whiteboard I used for homeschooling.

Comment: I have, but I thought it'd be kinda fun to build it myself. Concerning the lip, I was thinking that I could just add it onto the easel itself. I have slanted walls in the room where I am going to put it, so there are no flat surfaces for it :(